# evaluate using Cauchy's formula

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I evaluate this integral? I can't use Cauchy's formula directly.
$$ \int_{\lvert z-1\rvert=2}  \frac{1}{z^2-2i}dz $$

I used partial fraction to rewrite this integral as
$$ \int_{\lvert z-1\rvert=2}  \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}e^{-\pi/4}}{z-\sqrt{2}e^{\pi/4}}dz - \int_{\lvert z-1\rvert=2}  \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}e^{-\pi/4}}{z+\sqrt{2}e^{\pi/4}}dz $$
what should I do next?

Comment: Identify the singularity first and go from there

Comment: I can use partial fraction to rewrite this integral, but the second singularity $-\sqrt{2}e^{\pi/4} $ is not in the interior of the path, what should I do next?

Comment: If a singularity is not enclosed by your path, it is for all intents and purposes irrelevant, i.e. the integral in such a case would be zero. More explicitly, say we have a closed path $\gamma$ (on which $a \in \Bbb C$ does not lie) and $f(z)$ itself has no singularities. Then consider the integral

$$\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a}dx$$

If the region enclosed by $\gamma$ contains $a$, then you evaluate it as normal. If not, then the integral is $0$.

Comment: why the integral is 0 if the singularity is not enclosed by the path, can you give more details? Is it because of the first Cauchy's theorem: if f is analytic on a domain which is simply connected, then the integral along a closed path is 0?

Comment: Yes.  That's why.